# SVG's SMIL animations (<animate>, <set>, etc.) are deprecated, how to know from which lib?

Tags: google-chrome, smil

so I have a very large project and I am getting a chrome warning of:

`SVG's SMIL animations (<animate>, <set>, etc.) are deprecated`

how can I find our which lib is causing the warning (i.e. using smil)?

regards

Sean

Answer (score 0):

A quick way would be to search for the 'animate' or 'set' keyword in your project directory. This can be done easily in an IDE, for example in WebStorm IDE **ctrl+shift+f** lets you search through the entire project directory.